# ORA-02292 ConstraintViolationException when trying do delete parent of bidirectional relation with CascadeType.ALL

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entities being in typical parent-child relation: RoutingType that can have multiple RoutingParameters. JPA mapping looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROUTING_TYPE")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class RoutingType {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "routingType", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<RoutingProperty> properties = new HashSet<>();

    // Getters & Setters
    
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "ROUTING_PROPERTY")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class RoutingProperty {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROUTING_TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
    private RoutingType routingType;

    // Getters & Setters
    
}
```

To manage the data I use spring JpaRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface RoutingTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<RoutingType, Long> {
}
```

My problem is that when I try to delete the parent (RoutingType) having at least one RoutingProperty, then I get the ConstraintViolationException.

This is how I delete the object:

```
routingTypeRepo.deleteById(id);
```

And these are detailed logs with sql statements:

```
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select routingtyp0_.id as id1_93_0_, routingtyp0_.name as name2_93_0_, routingtyp0_.property_priority as property_priority3_93_0_, routingtyp0_.version as version4_93_0_ from routing_type routingtyp0_ where routingtyp0_.id=?
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [646]
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select properties0_.routing_type_id as routing_type_id4_88_0_, properties0_.id as id1_88_0_, properties0_.id as id1_88_1_, properties0_.name as name2_88_1_, properties0_.routing_type_id as routing_type_id4_88_1_, properties0_.param as param3_88_1_, properties0_.web_service_endpoint_id as web_service_endpoi5_88_1_, webservice1_.id as id1_104_2_, webservice1_.authorization_type as authorization_type2_104_2_, webservice1_.name as name3_104_2_, webservice1_.password as password4_104_2_, webservice1_.url as url5_104_2_, webservice1_.username as username6_104_2_ from routing_properties properties0_ left outer join web_service_endpoint webservice1_ on properties0_.web_service_endpoint_id=webservice1_.id where properties0_.routing_type_id=?
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [646]
org.hibernate.SQL                        : delete from routing_properties where id=?
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [884]
org.hibernate.SQL                        : delete from routing_type where id=? and version=?
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [646]
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [0]
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 2292, SQLState: 23000
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-02292: integrity constraint (FK_ROUTINGPROPERTY_ROUTINGTYPE) violated - Child record found

o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
o.z.p.spring.web.advice.AdviceTrait      : Internal Server Error

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [FK_ROUTINGPROPERTY_ROUTINGTYPE]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

The weard thing about this case is that in the logs we can clearly see that hibernate deletes RoutingProperty before RoutingType deletion, but Oracle still complains that there's record found.
I should add that all statements are executed at the transaction commit, not at the moment of RoutingTypeRepository.deleteById() method call.

What am I missing? Is there some possibility that Hibernate executes SQL queries in different order than logged?

I use Java 8, Spring Boot 2.0.3, Hibernate 5.2.17.Final, Oracle 11.2.0.3.0.